# Cron Job failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, cron

```
INCLUDE './config/databases.php';
require './vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

When i execute this script from browser i get no warning / issues .
but when i put same script for Cron  job

```
Warning: include(./config/databases.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/webdir/public_html/corn_mail.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening './config/databases.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/webdir/public_html/corn_mail.php on line 2

Warning: require(./vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/webdir/public_html/corn_mail.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/webdir/public_html/corn_mail.php on line 3
```

also tried to change from `./config/databases.php` to `/home/webdir/public_html/config/databases.php` Still the same.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Sidenote: It's "cron", not "corn" ;-) sounds like.... *oh never mind.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry for typo

Comment: Have you tried adding `dirname(__FILE__)` to the start of your include paths?

Comment: Does user under which you are running cron have appropriate permissions on those files?

Comment: @MikeBrant thought the same at first , checked error logs , none.. yes i am running cron as an root

Comment: Can you try the below command in terminal and tell what is the result.
"ls /home/webdir/public_html/config/databases.php"

Comment: `# ls /home/webdir/public_html/config/databases.php`
`/home/webdir/public_html/config/databases.php`
`# file /home/webdir/public_html/config/databases.php`
`/home/webdir/public_html/config/databases.php: PHP script text` @SanjayKumarNS

Comment: and where is your script file?folder structure?

Comment: `/home/webdir/public_html/`

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing the `./` - `config/databases.php` and if the `vendor` is in same folder then `vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php`. No need of `./`.